# being aware of IP Changes

Tags: windows, ip

I'm writing a program that needs to be aware of all IP addresses a machine and the packets are transfered through their connections. I can get the IP list before running of the main program with "gethostbyname", but what if any IP is available after that? Well having a loop with let say 1 minute sleep for each iteration and updating the IP list can help me but it's not accurate and I may lose some of the packages! Is there any other way?
I'm using Windows and C++

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure on your actual requirements but I would start by calling

```
NotifyIpInterfaceChange
```

which is part of the IPHelper API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814450(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Yesss, thanks! and "NotifyAddrChange" can be used for windows XP.